# Problem retrieving devices from Kismet through REST endpoint

Tags: curl, kismet-wireless

I am not able to retrieve the json data from kismet rest api endpoint through Curl. The problem is it asks for the password even though I have specified it. 
I have tried diffrent ways like

```
    curl -u root:friends http://localhost:2501/devices/all_devices.ekjson
```

I have also tried

```
    curl  http://root:friends:localhost:2501/devices/all_devices.ekjson
```

I keep getting the error

## 401 - Access denied

Login required to access this resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/devices/all_sources` instead of `/devices/all_devices`